# 404 really basic python flask app

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

writing my first web app using python, can't get the importing/routing concept

my app/**init.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import t


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000, debug=True)
```

then, my app/t.py :

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hi!'
```

http://127.0.0.1:3000/  - not found :(

any sensible reason for that?

ps. everything works like magic when i put routing to my init.py though

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hi!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000, debug=True)
```

so i though there must be something with the way import things :/

Comment: Does it work if you remove the port part?

Comment: no :(  now its not found under http://127.0.0.1:5000/ :(

Comment: ive always used 0.0.0.0 as my binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the skeleton that works best for me after going live with some flask apps.

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── t.py
└── run.py
```

where `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import t
```

`t.py`:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hi!'
```

and `run.py`:

```
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000, debug=True)
```

This way you can run the server with `python run.py`. This will save you the trouble of launching ther server in production with the `flask run` command.

Answer (score 0):

The flask command is totally different from  flask.run method. You can use passing arguments from command

Have you tried : `flask run -h localhost -p 3000`

Answer (score 0):

When you run the Flask application using Flask CLI ( Command Line Interface ) likely your `app.run(??)` not execute. It's nature of the Python itself when you run `python app.py` it will execute **init** method first. After that will execute everything defined in the init method. So when other program invokes your `app.py` the `__init__` method will never run.

In your case flask run just get the app context in your file and try to run with default port. Explicitly you can pass `--port` or `-p` for the desired `port`.